# Model is not being created by AJAX

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I want to create a `View` model that is created when a user finishes watching a lesson. The model should have a course id and a user id attribute. But Ajax doesn't create the view model after a lesson has been watched:

application.js:

```
$('#video').onended(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url:  '/views/new'
    type: 'post'
  });
});
```

Views Controller:

```
def create
  @view = current_user.views.build
  @view.lesson = Lesson.find(params[:lesson_id])
end
```

View Migration:

```
def change
  create_table :views do |t|
    t.integer :lesson_id
    t.integer :user_id

    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

View Model:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :lesson
```

User Model:

```
has_many :views
```

Lesson Model:

```
has_many :views
```

Routes:

```
post 'views/new' => 'views#create'
```

Lessons/show.html.erb:

```
<h2><%= @lesson.name %></h2>
<video id="video" controls="true" width="auto" 
height="auto">
<source src="<%= url_for(@lesson.file) %>" 
type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

Comment: can you also show us the results of your initial debugging? Only saying it doesn't work doesn't give us much to go on.

Comment: You are not calling `save` on the `@view` object. You just built a view and assigned a leeson but you never saved it.

Comment: You can do something like `@view = current_user.views.create(lesson_id: params[:lesson_id])` too

Comment: @arieljuod I tried that. The View model still does not get created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your AJAX you do not pass `params[:lesson_id]` in any way, so in controller it ends up being `Lesson.find(nil)`, which raises `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` and controller renders error 404 (check browser's console for that).

```
<video id="video" data-id="<%= @lesson.id %>" controls="true" width="auto" height="auto">
```

```js
$('#video').onended(function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  $.ajax({
    url:  '/views/new'
    type: 'post',
    data: {
      lesson_id: id
    }
  });
});
```

Also you do not save built object, use `create!` (the bang version raises error if it cannot save):

```
def create
  @view = current_user.views.create!(lesson: Lesson.find(params[:lesson_id]))
end
```